# JSP: constructing variables names

Tags: java, jsp

Inside a JSP, I need to programmatically construct variable names to access, e.g.

List of variables

- `${variable1}`
- `${variable2}`
- `${variable3}`
- `${variable4}`

Using a `<c:forEach>` with `${variable + i}` will not suffice, since `i` is sum to the variable. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean "*Using a `<c:forEach>` with `${variable + i}` will not suffice, since `i` is sum to the variable*"?

Comment: Sounds like it could be better to use an array or map than the way you are trying, don't you think?

Comment: Using a for with `i` will not work, since ${variable + i} will substitute the value of ${variable} added to ${i}

Answer (score 2):

Use the `<jsp:useBean class="java.util.HashMap">` trick.

```html
<jsp:useBean id="variables" class="java.util.HashMap" />
<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
    <c:set target="${variables}" property="variable${loop.index}" value="some" />
    ...
</c:forEach>
```

This basically creates a `HashMap` in the page scope and puts the given variables as map keys. The associated map value is free to your choice. You can even use EL in it.

In order to access it, just use `${variables['variable1']}` the usual way and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array with "i" as the index.